# summing values in a hash

Tags: ruby, hashmap

What is the best way to sum hash values in ruby:

```
@price = { :price1 => "100", :price2 => "100", :price3 => "50" }
```

I do something like this right now:

```
@pricepackage = @price[:price1] + @price[:price2] + @price[:price3] + 500
```

Please explain your answer, I want to learn why and not just how. =)

Comment: What are those close parentheses? Your Ruby code is not valid.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

You can do:

```
@price.values.map(&:to_i).inject(0, &:+)
```

EDIT: adding explanation

So @price.values returns an array that collects all the values of the hash. That is for instance `["1", "12", "4"]`. Then `.map(&:to_i)` applies `to_i` to each of the elements of this array and thus you get `[1,12,4]`. Lastly `.inject(0,&:+)` preforms inject with initial value 0 and accumulating using the function `+`, so it sums all the elements of the array in the last step.

Comment: please explain your answer =)

Comment: it's meta-programming, one of the most unique and awesome ruby features  :P (http://www.youtube.com/watch?v=kNpcaaL_dZA)

Comment: @Ivaylo Strandjev thanks =) I will shortly accept you answer.

Comment: @Ivaylo Strandjev, and if I want to add a another integer value for the sum, is good just to do something like this: @price.values.map(&:to_i).inject(0, &:+) + 500

Comment: `inject(0, &:+)` can be simplified to `inject(&:+)`.  When you don't supply an initial value, `inject` will use the first value of the enumeration as the initial value.

Comment: @SHUMAcupcake simply pass 500 as initial value to inject(i.e. it's first argument)

Comment: @WayneConrad you are right but in this particular case OP will actually need to pass initial value (see my comment above)

Comment: I forget to add that I would like to take one hash value and mutliple it with 15. like this: @pricepackage = @price[:price1] * 15 + @price[:price2] + @price[:price3] + 500 , how do I do that?

Answer (score 2):

If your data set looks like this:

```
prices = {price1: 100, price2: 100, price3: 50}
```

then this will sum the values:

```
prices.values.inject(0) {|total, v| total += v}
```

Comment: Or just `prices.values.inject(:+)`

Answer (score 1):

Keep it simple

```
@prices = ....
@price = 0.0

@prices.each do |p|
   @price += p
end
```